# Xamarin.iOS native crash at AVPlayer pause

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, avplayer

In recent updates to Xamarin Forms 4.8, I encountered crashes randomly when the AVPlayer is paused.  The Output window contains many rows of these outputs:

```
 8          124
00000046:  0128  3          2            3
00000052:  0131  2         12          132
0000005E:  0132  2         20          144
000000A6:  0100  4          4          256
000000B2:  0101  4          4          180
000000BE:  0102  3          6          266
000000CA:  0103  3          2            6
000000D6:  0106  3          2            6
000000E2:  0115  3          2            3
000000EE:  0201  4          4          272
000000FA:  0202  4          4         3475
0000000A:  0100  4          4           68
00000016:  0101  4          4           48
00000022:  0102  3          6          110
0000002E:  011A  5          8          116
0000003A:  011B  5          8          124
00000046:  0128  3          2            3
00000052:  0131  2         12          132
0000005E:  0132  2         20          144
000000A6:  0100  4          4          256
000000B2:  0101  4          4          180
000000BE:  0102  3          6          266
000000CA:  0103  3          2            6
000000D6:  0106 
 3          2            6
000000E2:  0115  3          2            3
000000EE:  0201  4          4          272
000000FA:  0202  4          4         3665
0000000A:  0100  4          4           68
00000016:  0101  4          4           48
00000022:  0102  3          6          110
0000002E:  011A  5          8          116
0000003A:  011B  5          8          124
00000046:  0128  3          2            3
00000052:  0131  2         12          132
0000005E:  0132  2         20          144
000000A6:  0100  4          4          256
000000B2:  0101  4          4          180
000000BE:  0102  3          6          266
000000CA:  0103  3          2            6
000000D6:  0106  3          2            6
000000E2:  0115  3          2            3
000000EE:  0201  4          4          272
000000FA:  0202  4          4         4269
0000000A:  0100  4          4           88
00000016:  0101  4          4           88
00000022:  0102  3          6          110
0000002E:  011A  5          8          116
0000003A
```

If I have waited for more than 10 seconds, the resume playback works fine.  Occasionally, immediate playback works too.  Unfortunately, immediate playback crashes the app.

Any suggestion is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you mean this not occurs before Xamarin Forms 4.8, and could you share the part code of `AVPlayer` where crashes?  It will be helpful to check where problem is.

Comment: Yes.  I started to face this random crash in Xamarin.Forms 4.8. I forked the InTheHand.Forms cross platform code.  From its github repository, it looks like it has been merged into Xamarin.Forms 4.8.  So, I am not sure whether that is the cause of the issue.  (I needed to fork it because I need to implement background audio in Android.)

Comment: Is it possible to show where it is being merged into Xamarin.Forms 4.8?

Comment: Okey, it will be possible. If you don’t have to use the 4.8 version and can not find where code or library can occur this, I will sugeest that downgrade to the previois version of Xamarin Forms to make it works.